# select unselect option in multiple select box onmousedown

Tags: jquery, html-select, multiple-select

I tried to change the handling of multiple select boxes to select and unselect options just by clicking on them (without using CTRL+click). Till Firefox was updated, everything worked as expected, but now only the clicked one is marked as selected and nothing else happened. I used the following code for select and unselect an option (worked till Firefox 25.0):

```
$(this).find('option').mousedown(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
    $(this).selected(false); // function that sets elements to selected/checked etc or not
 } else {
    $(this).selected(true); 
 }
 selectElement.change();
 return false;
});
```

The other thing I found out while I was trying several things was, that "$(this).is(':selected')" returns the wrong value if an option was selected once (for the first time or an other was selected before). E.g. option "a" is selected and marked so far. I selected an other one and then try to unselect option "a". For the first time, nothing happens (option "a" is selected), but if I select option "a" a second time, the system sees it as selected and trys to unselect it (what doesn't work as described above).

Has anybody a solution. For the alternative usage of a multiple select box I only found the code above?

Comment: You don't need javascript for this, you can select/deselect options in a multi-select by CTRL+clicking them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I forgot to mention that I used this script to avoid the usage of CTRL when clicking on the options.